# Oauth2 jwt token enriched with userinfo enpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

I have a spring application that exposes some webflux endpoints, I use a jwt token to authorize the post calls but we I also need the information given by the userinfo endpoint.
I have a SecurityWebFilterChain bean right now and we are using an oauth2ResourceServer configuration then calling the userinfoendpoint for further checks.
What is the best way to validate a jwt token then get the userinfo enpoint information for further validations?

ps: the authorization server is a third part one.

Security configuration without the external call for the user-info

```
  @Bean
  public SecurityWebFilterChain filterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {

    http
      .cors()
      .and()
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .csrf().disable()
            .logout().disable()
            .oauth2Client()
            .and()
      .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.POST).authenticated()
            .anyExchange().permitAll()
            .and().oauth2ResourceServer().jwt()
            ;

    return http.build();
  }
```

Comment: When you say "for further validations" can you give an example?

Comment: by not using a JWT and instead use a opague token instead of building some strange weird custom flow.

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg we need to take a field from the user info endpoint response, map it and add it to the authority

Answer (score 0):

The [UserInfo Endpoint](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#UserInfo) is part of [OpenID Connect 1.0](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html), and returns user information for an access token. It is not automatically called from a resource server (`http.oauth2ResourceServer()`) by Spring Security.

Based on your security configuration, it looks like you're wanting to use both OAuth2 Client (`http.oauth2Client()`) and OAuth2 Resource Server (`http.oauth2ResourceServer()`) in the same application. OAuth2 Client isn't designed for this use case (calling UserInfo from a resource server), and therefore would require customization to be adapted for such a case. Instead, you can simply use a `RestTemplate` or `WebClient` to call the UserInfo endpoint yourself.

You can do this in a custom `Converter<Jwt, Collection<GrantedAuthority>>` (or in this case the reactive version) like so:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .authorizeExchange((authorize) -> authorize
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2
                .jwt((jwt) -> jwt
                    .jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter())
                )
            );
        // @formatter:on

        return http.build();
    }

    private Converter<Jwt, Mono<AbstractAuthenticationToken>> jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
        ReactiveJwtAuthenticationConverter converter = new ReactiveJwtAuthenticationConverter();
        converter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter());
        return converter;
    }

    private Converter<Jwt, Flux<GrantedAuthority>> jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter() {
        JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter delegate = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
        return (jwt) -> getUserInfo(jwt.getTokenValue())
            .flatMapIterable((userInfo) -> {
                Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = delegate.convert(jwt);
                // TODO: Add authority from userInfo...
                return authorities;
            });
    }

    private Mono<Map<String, String>> getUserInfo(String accessToken) {
        // TODO: Call user info and extract one or more claims from response
        return Mono.just(new HashMap<>());
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is way more efficient to decode the data from a JWT than querying an external endpoint.

As a consequence, the best option is to configure the authorization-server (even if it is 3rd party)  to enrich the JWTs (access and ID tokens) with the data you need for authorization. Most OIDC authorization-servers support it, just refer to its documentation (Keycloak, Auth0, Cognito, ...).

Once all the claims you need are in access-tokens, you can read it on resource-server from the `JwtAuthenticationToken` instance (or `OAuth2AuthenticationToken` for client app with `oauth2login`) in the security-context. This allows to write stuff like:

```java
@PostMapping("/answers/{subject}")
@PreAuthorize("#userSubject == #auth.token.claims['sub']")
public ResponseEntity<String> addAnswer(@PathVariable("subject") String userSubject, @RequestBody @Valid AnswerDto, JwtAuthenticationToken auth) {
     ...
}
```